# Node.JS Express 4 - Mongoose Does not saving data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bluebird

I am trying to save a data in [**MongoDB**](https://www.mongodb.com/) with [**Mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/) with [**Express.JS 4**](https://expressjs.com/) and [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

What I have done is like this-

### bin/www

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

.......
.......

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function()
{// successfully connected!
    console.log("Successfully Connected to Mongo-DB");
});
```

And getting this in console-

```
Successfully Connected to Mongo-DB` - So, MongoDB connected successfully
```

### models/post.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created_by: String,     //should be changed to ObjectId, ref "User"
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    text: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

### app.js

```
var Post_Data = require("./models/post");
....
....
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    var Post = mongoose.model("Post");

    var post    =   new Post({
                            created_by: ""+Math.random()
                        });

    console.log( Post.create(post) );


    res.render(
                'index',
                {
                    title       :   'Express',
                    site_name   :   'Our Site',
                    layout      :   'templates/layout'
                }
            );
});
```

And after that I am getting this in console-

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

But, **nothing is saved**, a proof for that is -

I am finding this-

[image]

After using [**MongoBooster**](http://mongobooster.com/).

Update-

My DB config is like this-

```
"MONGO_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/express_test",
"MONGO_OPTIONS": {
                    "db": { "safe": true },
                    "name":"express_test"
                }
```

So, can anyone please help, why it is not saving anything?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) function is a shortcut for `new Model` and [`.save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save). You are trying to `.create` an instance of `Model` rather than a simple Object. See [Constructing documents in Mongoose's Models documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) for their quick example.

The return from a Mongoose data function is just the promise of an asynchronous task to be run in the future, logging that is largely pointless. Use [`.then()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/then.html) to wait until the promise has been resolved.

Error handling is missing from your code as well, something could be getting thrown there.  Use a [`.catch()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) for promise error handling.

```
Post.create({ created_by: ""+Math.random() })
.then(function (result) {
  console.log('Saved' result)
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error('Oh No', err)
})
```

All of this can be done with callbacks (like the Mongoose docco examples) but promises, particularly bluebird promises are nicer.

Comment: Hi @Matt , it is not working.

Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Mongoose does have a habit of silently failing when you don't have an open connection, although if you've seen the connection message and no `connection error` then that's unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I just use this syntax combination to create and save my model:

```
var myPage = new LandingPage({
  user:req.user,
  slug: req.body.slug,
}).save(function(err,savedModel){
  if(!err){
    console.log(savedModel);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did u ever try it yourself?

Please don't try to copy other's answer to answer a question.

Comment: this code is from one of my production codes, not copy pasted and its fully working !

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the wrong model in your `app.js` module as you are importing the model as

```
var Post_Data = require("./models/post"); // <-- Post_Data model never used
....
....
```

but creating a new `Post` model instance in your router implementation as

```
var Post = mongoose.model("Post"); // <-- different model

var post    =   new Post({
                        created_by: ""+Math.random()
                    });
```

You need to call and use the correct models. So I would suggest you re-write your `app.js` module to use the **[`save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)** method as:

```
var Post = require("./models/post"); // <-- import correct Post model
....
....
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post({ created_by: ""+Math.random() });
    post.save().then(function(post) {
        console.log(post); // <-- newly created post
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express',
            site_name: 'Our Site',
            layout: 'templates/layout'
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Oopsy', err);
    });
});
```

Comment: `mongoose.model('Post')` would return a `MissingSchemaError` if the model wasn't already setup.

Answer (score 1):

if you store post schema in a variable by require then can use that variable.

```
var Post_Data = require("./models/post");
```

so can use `new Post_Data` no need to use `var Post = mongoose.model("Post");` because you have already exported this schema `module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);`

you can try this one :

```
var Post_Data = require("./models/post");
router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    var post = new Post_Data({created_by: ""+Math.random()});

    post.save(function(error, data) {
      if(error) {
         return res.status(500).send({error: 'Error occurred during create post'});
      }
      return res.render('index',{
          title       :   'Express',
          site_name   :   'Our Site',
          layout      :   'templates/layout'
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's true that if you're creating a document in memory by calling `new Post(values)` that you will save it with `post.save(cb);` rather than 'Post.create(post);`, but I'm thinking that the underlying issue (though this isn't easy to be certain of based on the code you're showing) is that you're connecting with the MongoDB driver, rather than mongoose itself.  Your`db` variable isn't shown to be declared in the code you posted, so I'm making it an assumption.

That said, if I'm right,  you need to call `mongoose.connect` or `mongoose.createConnection` in order for Mongoose to know it's connected to the db and save documents to it.  You *can* pass an existing connection to mongoose, so if you're already doing so then I apologize for my erroneous assumption.